# CodeBuild and CodeDeploy Success But Not Running Server for maven javaweb application

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, tomcat8, aws-code-deploy, aws-codebuild

I'm using codestart on aws server my codecommit and codebuild success but not deployed on tomcat server. These are buildspec.yml and appspec.yml

> buildspec.yml

```
    version: 0.1

    phases:
      install:
        commands:
          - echo Entering install phase...
          - wget http://mirror.olnevhost.net/pub/apache/maven/maven-3/3.3.9/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.tar.gz
          - tar xzvf apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.tar.gz -C /opt/
          - export PATH=/opt/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:$PATH
      pre_build:
        commands:
          - echo Entering pre_build phase...
          - echo Nothing to do in the pre_build phase...
      build:
        commands:
          - echo Entering build phase...
          - echo Build started on `date`
          - mvn -f pom.xml compile war:exploded
      post_build:
        commands:
          - echo Entering post_build phase...
          - echo Build completed on `date`
          - mv target/ROOT .
    artifacts:
      type: zip
      files:
        - target/ROOT.war
        - appspec.yml
      discard-paths: yes
```

> appspec.yml

```
    version: 0.0
    os: linux
    files:
      - source: ./ROOT.jar
        destination: /
```

Comment: Just on casual glance, should `./ROOT.jar` in your `appspec.yml` be `./target/ROOT.war` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **buildspec.yml** (need to modify)
- **appspec.yml** (delete)

### **buildspec.yml**

```
    version: 0.1

    phases:
      install:
        commands:
          - echo Entering install phase...
          - wget http://mirror.olnevhost.net/pub/apache/maven/maven-3/3.3.9/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.tar.gz
          - tar xzvf apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.tar.gz -C /opt/
          - export PATH=/opt/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:$PATH
      pre_build:
        commands:
          - echo Entering pre_build phase...
          - echo Nothing to do in the pre_build phase...
      build:
        commands:
          - echo Entering build phase...
          - echo Build started on `date`
          - mvn -f pom.xml compile war:exploded
      post_build:
        commands:
          - echo Entering post_build phase...
          - echo Build completed on `date`
          - mv target/ROOT .
    artifacts:
      type: zip
      files:
        - 'ROOT/WEB-INF/**/*'
        - 'ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/*'
        - 'ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/**/*'
        - 'ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/*'
        - 'ROOT/WEB-INF/lib-provided/*'
        - 'ROOT/WEB-INF/js/*'
        - 'ROOT/org/springframework/boot/loader/*' //if you are using spring boot application
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you provide any additional information on the errors, I'm not sure how to help you.

Couple of pointers:

1. You can go the Code Deploy > Deployments > Deployment Revision >
   Events and logs to figure out exactly what is going wrong.
2. If you have ssh access to your instance, you can go to
   /opt/code-deploy/deployment-root/deployment-logs to find out what is
   going wrong.